# extend and modify nested typescript interface

Tags: typescript, types

how can I add to the object in datasets[0]?

```
interface ChartState {
    labels: string[];
    datasets: [
        {
            label: string;
            backgroundColor: string[] | string;
            hoverBackgroundColor: string[] | string;
            data:  (string|number)[];
        }
    ];
}

export interface PieCharState extends ChartState {}
```

what I would like to add:

```
export interface BarCharState extends ChartState{
  datasets[0].barThickness: number;
}
```

** I know thats not how it spouse to be done (specifing the index etc) but thats the goal.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your new type by referencing and extending your dataset type like this:

First, extract the dataset type:

```
type _dataSetType = ChartState['datasets'][0];
```

then define your new dataset type for the barchart:

```
type _barChartDataSetType = _dataSetType & {
   barThickness: number;
}
```

Finally define your BarChartState:

```
export type BarCharState = ChartState & {
  datasets: Array<_barChartDataSetType>
}
```

which allows you do use it as expected:

```
const test: BarCharState = {
   labels: ['foo', 'bar'],
   datasets: [
      {
         label: 'foo',
         backgroundColor: '#fefefe',
         hoverBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
         data: ['a', 'b'],
         barThickness: 3,
      },
   ]
}
```

[Full Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5TAZTHSZAbwChlzkAbOAIwkoGcAuZBsKUAcwG0BdAbjIUAJgTgMIYZsm5CKFUvKUVqdSizYcQnQcuU1EAa05QA9gFcQw1KcqmoG9lz7IAPqyfbde%20elMA3aAAhIxMLKxs7Bw8tHl43GK5vH3JRfBZkAApNLlcQcwBbOigASj5kpQBfOWQBEmqSMABPAAcUAH00uBxJABVWlABeNExsPAIIbgByLokpKd5uAAY6xoHkdoMoDCwwABExHrB%20tuRhzsO%209YAyYjkt3vRgBEMQCAZpfKLoQQaIAA8WvYwMhmqcQttRuNCMMdmN8IRbopkLNJNIAIJQKBwJoAHk2WDh%200uxwGAD56iQSAhTCA2KD3mAWBC4dChncVLR6NJpjBTKYpgAaZBTLYLQVyVFSFiyZTIvSqegsKZ8gUSlIGF5hSzWWz2ZUAYhgEGNxqFNSUfkCUBCWrMOsi%20pFRpgrtd5pSXRlUzgQpFNHFFvkDyeLzeHxYAGZ1VUY7V6kA)